# Modify LiveData item fetched from Room

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-livedata

I have simple `RecyclerView`, which I fill with `LiveData`.

Activity:

```
viewModel.getBooks().observe(this, books -> booksAdapter.setBooks(books));
```

ViewModel:

```
public LiveData<List<Book>> getBooks() {
    books = booksRepository.getBooks();
    return books;
}
```

BooksRepository just calls this `DAO`'s method:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM books")
LiveData<List<Book>> getBooks();
```

Everything works as expected. However, in `RecyclerView`, I have `LIKE` button for every item, and I want to create `onClick` listener, which changes book's flag `FAVOURITE` accordingly. However, Room does not support that with `LiveData`, and it does not support `MutableLiveData` as well. 
One (not good) solution would be to send Application to adapter, where I would create repository and update Book entity "manually". But I know it is not a good idea to send `Application` to `adapter`.

Any idea how to make this? I just need to set one simple `boolean` column in Book entity. Thanks.

Comment: Do you use Android's ListAdapter (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter)? You should do so, or otherwise try calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` from within your adapter's `setBooks()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating a value within a livedata set will not update the underlying source. I would recommend updating your DAO to where when the user clicks the LIKE button, it updates the DB..which then in turn post an update to your livedata and the changes would be reflected on the view.

eg:

```
@Query("UPDATE books SET FAVOURITE = :value WHERE books.bookId = :bookId")
public abstract void setBookFavourited(boolean value, int bookId);
```

Also to note, you shouldnt need to pass Application to the adapter. Setup an interface within the adapter that tells the activity that a user pressed the favorite button.

In adapter:

```
public interface BookFavoriteListener {
    void onBookFavorited(Book book);
}
```

Implement the interface in your activity, then pass 'this' into the constructor of the adapter to set the listener.